# How do you set a resource ID for a token?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I try to implement a RESTFul webservice with OAuth using this guide: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks

I can successfully retrieve a token:

```
 curl -v -u android-bookmarks:123456 -X POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=password&username=User1&grant_type=password&scope=write&client_secret=12345&client_id=android-bookmarks"
```

Response:

```
{"access_token":"cdafc45f-924a-4f87-8bd0-e3e2bdffa540","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"609efba8-edd3-4ea3-be7b-78e449cec0ef","expires_in":43199,"scope":"write"}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

When I try to access the resource:

```
curl -G http://localhost:8080/bookmarks -H "Authorization: Bearer cdafc45f-924a-4f87-8bd0-e3e2bdffa540"
```

I get the following response:

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Invalid token does not contain resource id (oauth2-resource)"}
```

The Java class setting the resource id:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String RESOURCE_ID = "bookmarks";

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
        throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {
        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
                throws AuthenticationException {
            return authenticationManager.getOrBuild().authenticate(
                    authentication);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
        throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("android-" + RESOURCE_ID)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
            .authorities("ROLE_USER")
            .scopes("write")
            .secret("123456")
            .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

}
```

When I change this code to:

```
clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("android-" + applicationName)
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
        .authorities("ROLE_USER")
        .scopes("write")
        .secret("123456");
```

I can access the resource with the previously mentioned (curl) commands successfully.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out that I had to implement the interface ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter. The following implementation works perfectly:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override 
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         // @formatter:off
         http
         .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/bookmarks", "/bookmarks/**")    
         .and()
         .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
         // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
         resources.resourceId(OAuth2Configuration.RESOURCE_ID);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@nydiarra/secure-a-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-reference-to-angular-integration-e57a25806c50) (see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054496/spring-oauth2-invalid-token-does-not-contain-resource-id-oauth2-resource)). I copy pasted this answer and now it works - could you explain *why*? I'm not getting it because I thought I'm doing this in `AuthorizationServerConfig.java` (see the tutorial).